# How to Enumerate mDNS services in Windows 10?

Tags: uwp, mdns

I'm trying to use `DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher` in a `UWP` app to enumerate `mDNS` services:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    if (_dnsWatcher == null)
    {
        _dnsWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher("(System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId:=\"{4526e8c1-8aac-4153-9b16-55e86ada0e54}\")");
        _dnsWatcher.Added += DnsWatcher_Added;
        _dnsWatcher.EnumerationCompleted += DnsWatcher_EnumerationCompleted;
        _dnsWatcher.Removed += DnsWatcher_Removed;
        _dnsWatcher.Stopped += DnsWatcher_Stopped;
        _dnsWatcher.Updated += DnsWatcher_Updated;
        _dnsWatcher.Start();
    }
}
```

`Wireshark` shows no `mDNS` broadcast and only the `EnumerationCompleted` callback happens.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please make sure that if there're mDNS services.

Comment: Even if there's no mDNS services it should still send an mDNS query.

Comment: Don't worry about `EnumerationCompleted` event is fired. If a device is added to the system after the initial device enumeration completes, it would re-enumerate it. Only if you call `Stop()` method, it will stop the enumeration operation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add what you're watching for. Here's my working code:

```
            var proto = "_gopher._tcp"; // e.g. _http._tcp
        var queryString = $"System.Devices.AepService.ProtocolId:={{{DnsSdProtocol}}} AND System.Devices.Dnssd.ServiceName:=\"{proto}\" AND System.Devices.Dnssd.Domain:=\"local\"";

        var askFor = new String[] { "System.Devices.Dnssd.HostName",
                            "System.Devices.Dnssd.ServiceName",
                            "System.Devices.Dnssd.InstanceName",
                            "System.Devices.IpAddress",
                            "System.Devices.Dnssd.PortNumber",
                            "System.Devices.Dnssd.TextAttributes",
                            };
        dw = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(queryString, askFor, DeviceInformationKind.AssociationEndpointService);
```

Note that my query string includes a protocol to search for (_gopher._tcp) and a dns domain. Caveat: I'm new at DNS-SD, and I don't know what dns domain settings are valid.